# WPF binding to ComboBox SelectedItem when reference not in ItemsSource

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, combobox

I'm binding the `PageMediaSize` collection of a `PrintQueue` to the `ItemSource` of a `ComboBox` (This works fine).  Then I'm binding the `SelectedItem` of the `ComboBox` to the `DefaultPrintTicket.PageMediaSize` of the `PrintQueue`.  While this will set the selected value to the `DefaultPrintTicket.PageMediaSize` just fine it does not set the initially selected value of the `ComboBox` to the initial value of `DefaultPrintTicket.PageMediaSize`  This is because the `DefaultPrintTicket.PageMediaSize` reference does not match any of the references in the collection.  However I don't want it to compare the objects by reference, but instead by value, but `PageMediaSize` does not override Equals (and I have no control over it).  What I'd really like to do is setup a `IComparable` for the `ComboBox` to use, but I don't see any way to do that.  I've tried to use a `Converter`, but I would need more than the value and I couldn't figured out how to pass the collection to the `ConverterProperty`.  Any ideas on how to handle this problem.

Here's my xaml

```
<ComboBox x:Name="PaperSizeComboBox" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=PrintersComboBox, Path=SelectedItem, 
                        Converter={StaticResource printQueueToPageSizesConverter}}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding ElementName=PrintersComboBox, 
                         Path=SelectedItem.DefaultPrintTicket.PageMediaSize}"
          DisplayMemberPath="PageMediaSizeName"
          Height="22"
          Margin="120,76,15,0"
          VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

And the code for the converter that gets the `PageMediaSize` collection

```
public class PrintQueueToPageSizesConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
                          System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value == null ? null :
            ((PrintQueue)value).GetPrintCapabilities().PageMediaSizeCapability;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, 
                          System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**Edit**

I tried setting the `DefaultPrintTicket.PageMediaSize` to the corresponding reference in the collection before `InitializeComponent`, but that did not work.  It's definately setting the value when I select something from the `ComboBox`, but it doesn't seem to go the other way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would it be possible to create a wrapper class for `PageMediaSize` and override the `Equals(object)` method in this wrapper class? You could then add instance of this wrapper class to your collection, so that they are no longer compared by reference. Of course, you will need some code for wrapping and unwrapping your `PageMediaSize` instances, but that's the best way I can imagine.

Answer (score 1):

Further to juharr's answer, you could use a converter to wrap and unwrap the object.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace MyNameSpace
{
    public class ToTypeEqualityWrapper : IValueConverter
    {
        public class TypeEqualityWrapper
        {
            public object Value { get; set; }

            public TypeEqualityWrapper(object value)
            {
                Value = value;
            }

            public override bool Equals(object obj)
            {
                var otherWrapper = obj as TypeEqualityWrapper;
                if (otherWrapper == null)
                    return false;

                var result = Value.GetType().FullName == otherWrapper.Value.GetType().FullName;
                return result;
            }
        }

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var list = value as IList;
            if (list != null)
            {
                return (from object item in list select new TypeEqualityWrapper(item)).Cast<object>().ToList();
            }

            return new TypeEqualityWrapper(value);
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var wrapper = value as TypeEqualityWrapper;
            if(wrapper != null)
                return wrapper.Value;

            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

Then declare your converter

```
<ns:ToTypeEqualityWrapper x:Key="toTypeEqualityWrapper" />
```

In the xaml, use the converter on both ItemSource and Selected Item.

```
<ComboBox                                                               
    ItemsSource="{Binding MySource, Converter={StaticResource toTypeEqualityWrapper}}" 
    SelectedItem="{Binding MySelectedItem, Converter={StaticResource toTypeEqualityWrapper}}"                                                             
    DisplayMemberPath="Value.DisplayName" />
```